# What's the damage if I accidently remove the libX11 package?

Tags: x11, package-management

I accidently remove the libX11 package using the repository manager.
The repository manager seems to remove all the other packages which depend on libX11.
After removing, when I restart my computer, the gui won't display.
So I think repository manager has removed the DE I installed.
I'm wondering whether there's other damages has occured to my PC?
Can I simply resume to the original state by reinstall the DE?

I'm using SLES 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which distribution and package manager?
Most of them have a history/undo which will allow you to recover the removed packages or at least see a list of what you removed.

For yum that would be:

to see a list of entries in the history:

```
$ sudo yum history
```

to see the action that took place in an entry:

```
$ sudo yum history info 33
```

to undo these actions:

```
$ sudo yum history undo 33
```

Comment: I'm using sles 11 sp3, zypper

Comment: Then, you can find out what happened in /var/log/zypp/history
as far as I know, there's no equivalent for yum history in zypper